# can we rename first suffix of file from all subfoldes if found through batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I am renaming a resource files which first extension is 'hi-IN'. Now I need such a batch file which is change first extension to 'mr-IN' in a sub folders recursively. Some sub folders have no resource files.

file names are like this :

```
home.hi-IN.resx
home.en-GB.resx
index.hi-IN.resx
index.en-GB.resx
```

then output should be :

```
home.mr-IN.resx
home.en-GB.resx
index.mr-IN.resx
index.en-GB.resx
```

can we do this from batch script?

Comment: Nice. And what is your specific question? If you are expecting that we write code for you, then you are totally wrong here, as this is not a free code/script writing service. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: Based on your edit, **yes**!